# Compare values from another table that have no common key for a join clause

Tags: sql, join, range, ip-address, lookup

I have two tables (SQL). One contains an IP address (table a), and the other contains two fields that represent the start an end of an IP range (table b - range_from and range_to). Neither one of these tables contain a common key to perform a join. I need to pull the country code from table b based on the ip address contained in table a; based on that ip address being in the range_from and range_to in table b. So, in other words I need to look to see which range (table B range) that IP from table a is in and pull the country code that corresponds.
I have tried a few things but no luck. Any suggestions/ideas on how this can be accomplished?

### table a

> ip address       name                  order#          address  country
>
> ---
>
> 255.65.28.214 
>        Carlyle       7458214         45 N. East street      United States

### table b

> range_from       range_to            country_code
>
> ---
>
> 192.168.52.69    192.168.75.11       US
>
> ---
>
> 192.0.78.23      192.0.78.99         CN

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formal method:

```
select a.*, b.country_code
from tablea a join
     tableb b
     on a.ipaddress between b.range_from and range_to;
```

If you care about performance there are more efficient ways.  The most efficient is to create an index on `tableb(range_from, range_to, country_code)`.  Then if you assume there are no overlaps (because there aren't any) and there all your ip addresses in the first table match, then try:

```
select a.*,
       (select country_code
        from tableb b
        where b.range_from < a.ipaddress
        order by b.range_from desc
        limit 1
       ) as country_code
from tablea a;
```

Note that this uses `limit` to get one row.  That depends on the database and might be `top` or `fetch first 1 rows only` or something else.